# django QuerySet filter()

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model like this

```
class File(models.Model):

    folder=models.ForeignKey(Folder, null=True, blank=True)
    uploaded_file=models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',default=timezone.now())
    tag=models.ManyToManyField(FileTag)
    notes=models.TextField(max_length=200)
    uploader=models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.uploaded_file)
    #return os.path.basename(self.uploaded_file.name)

    def filename(self):
     return os.path.basename(self.uploaded_file.name)
```

i want to do somethig like this

```
        sr_files=File.objects.filter(filename__contains=keyword)
```

but i cannot use filter with filename() self defined function
Plz help

Here is my template code

```
    {% if sr_files %}
    <ul>
    {% for rf in sr_files %}
        <li><a href="/documents/{{rf.uploaded_file}}">{{ rf.filename }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No Files Found containing {{ keyword }}</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can't use properties and function's name in filter

This  can do  either using list compression or generator expression as follows:

```
# for single File object 
sr_file = next(
          (f for f in File.objects.filter() if keyword in f.filename()), 
          None)
```

or

```
# for: all File objects contains keywords in their file path: 
sr_files = [f for f in File.objects.filter() if keyword in f.filename()]
```

Comment: yes it gives me the desired output but i want sr_files to be the collection of File type object so that i can open the file by giving the appropriate link with id in File type object                                                                Here is my template code

Comment: @wrufesh in second List-compression expression `sr_files` is indeed the collection of File type objects. Over which you can iterate in template code.

Comment: @wrufesh Your welcome :), btw If you gets error in `rf.filename` in template code, make it property read this [Q & A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468804/django-template-call-function)s

Answer (score 1):

Return the part after the last `/` in a path is what `os.path.basename` does. So you could use [`regex` lookup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#std%3afieldlookup-regex)

```
import re
File.objects.filter(uploaded_file__regex='[^/]*{}[^/]*$'.format(re.escape(keyword)))
```

Or simply

```
files = File.objects.filter(uploaded_file__contains=keyword)
# Then discard false matches
files = (f for f in files if keyword in f.filename())
```