# Passing arguments to model methods in Django templates

Tags: django

I'm trying to get all customers from a specified business, but there is a class method in Customer model to get some information based on the same Business... Let me explain this with code...

```
class Business(models.Model):
    ...
    customers = models.ManyToManyField(Customer, blank=True, null=True)

class Customer(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_something(self, obj_business)
        ...
```

Ok now in my views I get all customers from a specified business like this:

```
obj_customers = obj_business.customers.all()
```

Then I try to print this in my template:

```
{% for obj_customer in obj_customers %}
    {{ obj_customer.get_something ....... }}
```

But yes, there is not a way to pass arguments... I would like to know if there is something that I'm missing...

I wonder if there is another solution instead creating a template tag... because it is a ManyToManyField, if **customers** field had been just ForeignKey, no need to pass an argument to that method...

Answer (score 59):

You can create a simple template tag to call any method with any arguments:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def call_method(obj, method_name, *args):
    method = getattr(obj, method_name)
    return method(*args)
```

And then in your template:

```
{% call_method obj_customer 'get_something' obj_business %}
```

But, of course, crating of a specialized template tag is more safe :-)

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_something(customer, business):
    return customer.get_something(business)
```

Template:

```
{% get_something obj_customer obj_business %}
```

Comment: could we save the result of call_method using `with`?

Comment: I would just suggest a link to the documentation to get a complete picture of how to include template tags in an app: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass arguments to functions in Django templates.

Instead you can write your own [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Here are some examples:

https://github.com/miohtama/LibertyMusicStore/blob/master/tatianastore/templatetags/content.py