# Django Passing Through List Items

Tags: python, django

I have a todo website that allows users to put a remind in a certain list, such as work, school, groceries, etc. However, I'm a bit lost on how to get the list name and their items to display.

Models.py:

```
class RemindList(models.Model):
    parent_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Reminder(models.Model):
    remind_types = [('Regular', 'Regular'), ('Long Term', 'Long Term')]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()  
    remind_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True) 
    parent_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    parent_list = models.ForeignKey(RemindList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    type_of_remind = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=remind_types, default='Regular')
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def home(request):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user.username)
    context = {
        'events': ToDoItem.objects.filter(parent_user=user),
        'reminders': Reminder.objects.filter(parent_user=user, type_of_remind='Regular'),
        'long_term_reminders': Reminder.objects.filter(parent_user=user, type_of_remind='Long Term'), 
        'remind_list_items': RemindList.objects.filter(parent_user=user),
    }
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

I can pass through the list names, and I planned to just loop through them and add `Reminder.objects.filter(parent_user=user, type_of_remind='Regular', parent_list=list_name)` to context. However, theres no way to loop through them on the html side (can't do for loop because there are other context types), and you can't filter them on the html side (correct me if I'm wrong). Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Huh, surely {% for reminder in remind_list_items %} should work just fine? I'm having trouble understanding what your problem is here?

Comment: I have that in my HTML, but reminder in your provided code isn't actually a reminder item. Remind_list_items is just a list of strings. I'm trying to loop through the titles and filter through the reminders based on the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it took me a few readings, but if what I understand is correct you want to be able to iterate over the ReminderList objects and also list out the Reminder items under each one.

My suggestion would be to add a method to ReminderList that returns the items in that list, you could then do something like this in your template

```
{% for list in reminder_lists %}
  ... List header stuff goes here ...
  {% for item in list.get_reminder_items %}
     ... Print the item ...
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

(The Django templating language can be a little interesting in that object.identifier can map to either an attribute or an object method - this can be useful for cases like these).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'll give it a try. Didn't know you could access methods from the html side. I thought everything had to be passed through as context.

Comment: One more thing- I tried to pass through parameters like `{% for item in list.get_reminder_items(user.get_username) %}` because I need the logged in user's username to filter the reminders. It gives me an error: Could not parse the remainder (user.get_username)

Comment: Yeah, there isn't really a way to pass parameters to methods unless you want to go and write yourself a custom template tag (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513528/passing-arguments-to-model-methods-in-django-templates)

Comment: Of course, if the parent user of the list can never differ from the parent user of the items, you probably don't even need the field on the items - and you'd just only include lists for the current user in your template. Of course, I don't know enough about your application to know if that works for you.