# Calling function with variable from view template, django

Tags: python, django

in template

```
{{object.get_resource}}
```

in views.py(DetailView)

```
def get_resource(self):
    return "my resource"
```

It works.

Now, I want to pass the variable to object.

Is it possible to do like this below?

```
{{object.get_resource(1)}}

def get_resource(self,num):
    return "my resource:{0}".format(num)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot pass arguments to functions in Django templates.

You ought to write your own template tags.

Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28513600/14364242) as reference :-)

Comment: I see. I will find the workaround, but thank you very much