# How to use some variable that call a function to put inside of HTML template in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

- I need to use that function below, here is in util.py

  ```
  def get_entry(title):
      try:
          f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
          return f.read().decode("utf-8")
      except FileNotFoundError:
          return None
  ```
- Then I put that in my views.py with the var "get"

  ```
  def getFunction(request):
      return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
          "get": util.get_entry()  
      })
  ```
- So I want to use that function in my index.html

  ```
  {% block body %}
      <h1>All Pages</h1>

      <ul>
          {% for entry in entries %}
              <a href="{% get %}"><li>{{ entry }}</li></a> //{% get %} doesn't work
          {% endfor %}
      </ul>
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- The only for is to show up a list with 5 items and inside of li, using entry I can display all five items (e.g: apple, banana, tomato, pear, grape)
- I need to use href because When I click it will to another folder/file .md that will be writed about apple for example
- I wanna use that function to take in my file .md
- If you need more informations just ask me. thank u. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call function that takes an argument in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468804/how-to-call-function-that-takes-an-argument-in-a-django-template)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an @property on models.py for the app the call entries.your_function

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```py
class YourModel(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # Add a property to your model
    @property
    def yourFunction(self):
        # steps
        return 'Hello from your template!'
```

Next just call it like this in your template

```html
{{ your_model_instance.yourFunction }}
```

You will see

```html
Hello from your template!
```