# Django/Python : Using json.loads in the template

Tags: python, json, django, templates

I am trying to use json.loads in my template in order to get a python's dictionnary. But unfortunately, i encounter the same error :

```
Could not parse the remainder: ' = json.loads(entry.saved_data)' from 'everyEntry = json.loads(entry.saved_data)'
```

Here is my code from the template :

```
 <tbody>
                <tr> 
                  {% for entry in entries %}

                {{everyEntry = json.loads(entry.saved_data)}}
                {{ everyEntry.items}}

                {% for clef, valeura in headersLoop %}
                {% for chiave, valore in everyEntry %}
                {% if clef = chiave %}
                <td>
                  <p>{{clef}} {{valore}}</p>
                </td>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}    
                </tbody>
```

An at this line :

```
 {{everyEntry = json.loads(entry.saved_data)}}
```

the problem occurs.

How may i fix this ?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to bruno and Aniket, i found the solution.

First i created a method that returns a dict items such as bruno example :

```
class YourModel(models.Model):   

`def entry_saved_data(self):

return json.loads(self.saved_data)
```

Then i made this loop into my template.html :

```
  <tr>
                {%for entry in entries%}
                {%for cle, valeur in entry.all_form_entry_json%}
                {%for key, valor in headersLoop%}
                {%if key == cle%}


                 <td> {{valeur}}</td>

                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}                   
                {% endfor %}                    
                </tr>
```

It prints all the datas. But one small problem appears. It doesn't fill the array in a proper way. Nevertheless all the datas from all the forms are printed.

:)

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1 - Define custom model method**

Create custom method in models.py,

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
   # your stuff

   def entry_saved_data(self):
      return json.loads(self.saved_data)
```

**Method 2 - Using template tags**

You can use template tags for doing so.If you are now aware of template tags you can find it in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/)

```
@register.simple_tag
def entry_saved_data(value):
   return json.loads(value)
```

Use it in template like,

```
{% load tags %}
{% entry_saved_data entry.saved_data as everyEntry %}
```

you now have json deserialized data in everyEntry variable.

Comment: Okay i implemented @register... in my views.py    Then i called it with {% load tags %} in the template.html but it shows me an error : "'tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library tags not found," I used the same syntax that you did. Maybe i put the first code (@register...) in the wrong folder ?

Comment: how you created the templatetags folder and you created 2 files named __init__.py and tags.py ?  Have you looked the above documentation link ? Anyways @bruno said defining method in models.py is also nice way.

Comment: I just read the line that talk about it. Thank you for your help and your patience. :) I check also bruno's method.

Comment: Yeah  bruno desthuilliers's suggestion is also nice and easy way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Do not write logic in templates.

Do `json.load` in **view** and pass it to template via context.

Comment: Yes, i know this fact. But, that's not what i expect. :) I'm trying to print all the entry transformed into python dictionnary first. Then changed into items in order to sort them with my headers' value. So if i use json.loads in view, i will only get one entry and not everyone.

Comment: Why not prepare the data in the view and only render data in the template?

Comment: Or add a method to your `entry` class that returns the parsed json data ?

Comment: That an idea yes ! I will try everything you said and i'll let u know.

Comment: I am trying to add a method in the models.py but i can't get all the entries transform into dict items. I can only get one entry which is in dict items. But not all of them. I stuck to this.

Answer (score 0):

see: ([functions in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242029/functions-in-django-templates))

Templates in django do not permit calls to arbitrary functions, that that is by design to the best of my knowledge.

That being said, you may be able to create a custom template tag that does what you want.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Okay I check everything then i'll let you know.

Comment: @aniket's code is probably the simplest solution. Make sure to look at "Auto Escaping Considerations" if you have HTML embedded in your JSON.