# How to solve the problem that json type data is loaded from template to string type

Tags: python, django

The "content" field is data in json format. But when I check this value in template , it resolves to string. I want to print the value corresponding to teacher from the dictionary below. What's wrong?

[views.py]

```
    history = History(user=request.user, 
                      study=study,
                      content=study.json())
    history.save()

    test = History.objects.filter(study__id='12')
```

"content" value stored in DB: {'id': 12, 'is_deleted': False, 'type': 'secondary', 'study_name': 'Math', 'teacher': 'Halen/Lisa', 'team': 'A'}

[html]

```
{% for test in test %}
    {{ test.content.teacher }}? {{ test.content}}
{% endfor %}
```

In the case of a dictionary, the desired key value can be called, but since it is a string type, the teacher value cannot be retrieved. What should the teacher do to get the value, which is the key?

Answer (score 0):

From [Python convert string dictionary to dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/), we can use

```
import json

history = History(user=request.user, 
                  study=study,
                  content=study.json())
history.save()

test = History.objects.filter(study__id='12')

test_content = json.loads(test.content)
```

OR

You can directly do json.loads() in the field using template tags as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45080029/11282077).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `literal_eval` if properties are with sing quotes:

```
import ast

...

test.content = ast.literal_eval(test.content)
```