# Why can I call the "all" method on my ManyRelatedManager without parenthesis? (Django)

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I'm following the tutorial in the Django documentation, and experimenting with models and views. I have a `Person` model, which has a many-to-many relationship to other Persons, which I call "friends". I wanted to show a list of people in my database, and their friends, so I tried the following template:

```
{% if people %}
    <ul>
    {% for p in people %}
        <li>
            {{ p.name }}
            <ul>
            {% for f in p.friends.all() %}
                <li>
                    {{ f.name }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>There are no people.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Django tells me that it cannot find the `all()` method. In a wild guess I try to take away the parentheses, leaving the line as follows `{% for f in p.friends.all %}`. To my surprise, this actually works, but I cannot understand why.

Am I actually calling the method and getting a query set back, or is something completely different going on?

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115869/calling-python-function-in-django-template/2115936#2115936 and this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables

Comment: Ah, that clears it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As Victor Castillo Torres points out in a comment, in Django templates you do not include parentheses in method calls. Only methods without parameters can be called, and these are called without parentheses.

Further details in the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables

Comment: I just don't see any explicit reference to the lack of parenthesis on the templates page